# Add Technical Indicator to chart.Posn

Tags: r, quantmod, quantstrat, blotter

For some reason I cannot add a ROC signal to a blotter chart. In the documentation it should be allowed. I want to create a new chart bellow with this indicator.
Can someone help?

```
# plot performance for symbol
chart.Posn(strategy_AbsMom, Symbol = 'SPY', Dates = '1998::',theme=myTheme)
chart.Posn(strategy_AbsMom, Symbol = 'SPY', Dates = '1998::',theme=myTheme,
           TA='addROC(n=lookback,col=4)')
```

Answer (score 3):

`chart.Posn` uses `chart_Series` (not `chartSeries`) internally, so you have to use `add_*` functions (not `add*`). Here's an example of adding a simple moving average to a `chart.Posn` chart:

```
require(blotter)
demo(amzn_test, ask=FALSE)
chart.Posn("amzn_port", "amzn", TA='add_SMA(n=5, col=4)')
```

[image]