# add custom TA to chart.Posn()

Tags: r, quantstrat, blotter

I have the same problem as: [Add Technical Indicator to chart.Posn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549654/add-technical-indicator-to-chart-posn)

However, I am working with a custom indicator and it is plotting on top of the positions chart. can someone assist me? The indicator I am working with is proprietary, but any defined custom-indicator solution would be helpful.

Here is my chart.Posn() call:

```
chart.Posn(Portfolio = strategy, 
           Symbol = tickers, 
           theme = myTheme, 
           Dates = "2016-01-20::2016-01-20",
           TA = "add_TA(range_expansion_index(OHLC(mktdata)))")
```

and this is what my output looks like (i have highlighted the problem in the red box):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

the solution that worked for me was the add_TA function. for example,

```
rei <- my_function(close_prices, period = 5) 

chart.Posn(Portfolio = strategy_nm, 
           Symbol = tickers, 
           theme = myTheme)

add_TA(rei, col = "black", lwd = 1.5, legend = "REI", type = 'l')
```